# Testing for a blank line ("paragraph") immediately after \begin{document}

Tags: environments, conditionals, indentation, paragraphs

(With this question, I hope to resolve an edge case relevant for my [quoting](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package.)

Suppose I define a customized environment for displayed text. It resembles the standard LaTeX environment `quote` (i.e., it is based on the `list` environment), but as a twist, the first line of the environment should be indented if (and only if) the environment is preceded by a blank line. At the moment, I accomplish this by testing for vertical mode (and setting `\itemindent` accordingly). However, this test fails for environments positioned immediately after `\begin{document}`. Whether I write

```
\begin{document}

\begin{myquote}% First line of following text should be indented
```

or

```
\begin{document}
%
\begin{myquote}% First line of following text shouldn't be indented
```

the first line of the `myquote` environment is always indented. (Seee full MWE below.) How should my test for a blank line ("paragraph") be amended/modified in order to also work immediately after `\begin{document}`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myquote}{%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{%
      \ifvmode
        \parindent
      \else
        \z@
      \fi
    }%
  }%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{myquote}
\emph{This line shouldn't be indented, but it is.} \sometext
\end{myquote}

Nomal running text. \sometext
%
\begin{myquote}
This line shouldn't be indented, and it isn't. \sometext
\end{myquote}

Normal running text. \sometext

\begin{myquote}
This line should be indented, and it is. \sometext
\end{myquote}

Normal running text. \sometext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you set the `itemindent`?

Comment: @Marco: Because that's the length that controls the indentation of the item's first paragraph. See the definition of `quotation` in `article.cls` -- it contains `\itemindent \listparindent`.

Comment: :Than I think in the second `myqoute` should be indented?

Comment: @Marco: No -- there's no blank line before it, but a line with a comment sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, but it possibly breaks if other environments that redefine `\par` are used at document start.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\lock@reset{\global\let\iflock@check\iffalse
  \global\let\par\endgraf
  \global\let\lock@reset\relax}
\appto\document{\let\iflock@check\iftrue\def\par{\endgraf\lock@reset}}

\newenvironment{myquote}{%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{%
      \ifvmode
    \iflock@check\z@\else\parindent\fi
      \else
    \z@
      \fi
    }%
  }%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist\lock@reset
}
\makeatother
```

## Caveat

The code seems to work, but I don't recommend using it, for a couple of reasons. First a practical one. How many documents begin with a quotation right after `\begin{document}`?

Second reason. Doing stuff with `\document` is a Bad Thing; actually the code can go into `\AtBeginDocument`, but what about other packages that act in the same way on `\par`?

Doing nasty tricks with `\par` just for the sake of symmetry is not worth the labor.

**@Lockstep**: please, don't add such a "feature" to your package; rather add a warning and a way to avoid indentation in a `quoting` environment just after `\begin{document}`; it's easier and will probably never be used.

Besides, the `quoting` environment *always* has an initial indentation when it follows some environments, with or without an intervening blank line: for example `flushleft`, `center`, `flushright` or `sloppypar`. So a key for deciding whether an indentation is desired might prove very useful.

Comment: Indeed -- seems to work! Do I understand correctly that `\endgraf` stores (or was `\let` to) the original meaning of `\par`?

Comment: It's also instructive how `\lock@reset` kills itself after its first application. :-)

Comment: Yes, `\endgraf` is a copy of primitive `\par`; it's a Plain thing, that's been carried over. There's also a more LaTeXish `\@@par`; look also for `\@par` in `latex.ltx`. Once `\lock@reset` has done once its business (at start of document or later) it's not needed any more.

Comment: In my `quoting` package, I have defined a boolean switch `quo@afterquo` that reports if a `quoting` environment is immediately (without a paragraph in between) preceded by another `quoting` environment. If so, vertical mode is ignored when setting the environments first-line indentation. But it didn't occur to me to use a similar trick to hook into `\document`. Answer accepted -- I hope it's okay that your code (or at least its general idea) will make it into a future version of `quoting` -- of corse, with proper attribution.

Comment: No problem with you using the code, of course; but, please, test it thoroughly: `\@doendpe` uses `\@restorepar` and this might have bad consequences. But maybe not.

Comment: The `quoting` environment disables `\@doendpe` and uses a modified clone `\quo@doendquo` instead, so yes, I'm aware that this is "dangerous terrain". I *will* test as thoroughly as a power user (not a programmer) is able to.

Comment: @egreg: I tested your code and works fine. I think a simple line works also: `\appto\document{\let\iflock@check\iftrue\def\par{\let\iflock@check\iffalse\@restorepar}}`

Comment: @Marco Yes: `\@restorepar` issues a (primitive) `\par`, but that's unimportant. But it's convenient also to kill `\lock@reset`, though it will be done anyway at the first usage of `mylist`.

Comment: @egreg: For a better understanding. Why do you need `\lock@reset` at the end? `\@restorepar` will be do the job.

Comment: @Marco Just not to do again and again those assignment at the end of the environment. If there's no initial `\par`, there would be no restoration.

Comment: @egreg: I understand. I doesn't consider that no par will follow. A normal `\global\let\iflock@check\iffalse` should also work. Maybe I need also bed ;-)

Comment: @Lockstep: look at the edited answer.

Comment: @egreg: Many thanks for your added comments. It is true that tinkering with `\par` might not be wort the hassle for an "edge case", as I called it from the start; also, you're right about the indentation after `center` and friends. I'll consider to add an `indent` package key with the possible values `auto`, `true`, and `false` to handle such cases.

Comment: @egreg: `quoting` 0.1a (with a new `indentfirst` option) is on its way to CTAN. Again, thanks for pointing out those additional "edge cases".